# batch update link_urls in the creative

Tags: facebook-graph-api, batch-file

We are trying to attach some parameters to existing `link_urls` for creatives. 
For example:

`http://www.adchemy.com -> http://www.adchemy.com?param_ad_id=23423424242 for tracking`

purposes, where is such id is an adgroup id for that creative.

We'll maintain one to one relation between creative and adgroup.

To update existing creative we have to create new and associate it with the ad. 
We need to update around 5000 creatives.

> Is there a way to update them in the batch rather than doing 10000 requests?

(5000 for new creatives and 5000 to update appropriate ads)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way in facebook API provides batch  updates https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/ not sure about the limit though it says 20.You can create Adgroups and insert creative element in the form of JSON or object and post information to adgroups url which is available at Open graph API 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adgroup/